# Simple error in configuration

Tags: pspice

Folks,

I' am getting below error :

> Design mode: (reason: ERROR: Load Verify). It may require classes (such as Adobe AIR components)
>   that are not supported by design mode. Check the Eclipse error log for
>   more details. Main.mxml   "Design view"   Problem

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is a known issue:

https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-24178

Good find.

Comment: I am trying to use Messaging functionality of Parsley as shown here : http://www.codesofmylife.com/2011/08/03/flex-messaging-with-parsley/.. but somehow I am not able to get the reqd output. I thought the above could not load spicelib-flex-2.4.0 may be the reason for that ..

Comment: What's the debug info. Maybe the injection is not done properly. Actually I don't often use design mode, I guess it may not be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

As kyohiro said, it is a known issue. Note: It is a **warning**, not an *error*. Your project should still be compilable and runnable.

Comment: I am trying to use Messaging functionality of Parsley as shown here : `http://www.codesofmylife.com/2011/08/03/flex-messaging-with-parsley/`.. but somehow I am not able to get the reqd output. I thought the above could not load `spicelib-flex-2.4.0` may be the reason for that ..

Comment: It's a "Design view" Problem. Whatever your code issue is, it is not this